# SQL Query : Facing issues to get desired records from different tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have two tables

1. Calendar (Calname, CCode, PCode)
2. Lookup (LCode, Name)

   Calendar table contains records like,

   ```
   Calname | CCode | PCode

   abc     | O_R   | P_R

   xyz     | C_R   | P_C
   ```

   Lookup table contains records like,

   ```
   LCode | Name

   O_R   | Reporting

   C_R   | Cross

   P_R   | Process

   P_C   | ProcessCross
   ```

I have to fetch the records in a way where I can get the name of all codes from lookup table which contains the record rowwise.

Desired Output,

```
    Calname | CCode | PCode | CCodeName | PCodeName

    abc     | O_R   | P_R   | Reporting | Process

    xyz     | C_R   | P_C   | Cross     | ProcessCross
```

I can not apply simply inner join on the basis of code it will not give me desired output.
I tried to use subquery also but it not worked out somehow,
.
Can anyone help me out with this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Join to the lookup table twice with different alias'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to Tim's answer would be to use scalar subqueries, which may or may not give you some performance benefit due to scalar subquery caching:

```
SELECT
    c.Calname,
    c.CCode,
    c.PCode,
    COALESCE((SELECT l1.name FROM lookup l1 WHERE c.ccode = l1.lcode), 'NA') AS CCodeName,
    COALESCE((SELECT l2.name FROM lookup l2 WHERE c.pcode = l2.lcode), 'NA') AS PCodeName
FROM Calendar c;
```

I would test both answers to see which one works best for your data.

Comment: Thanks its a great help, after trying this I am facing this error >> ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
*Cause:   then I used COALESCE((SELECT l1.name FROM lookup l1 WHERE c.ccode = l1.lcode  and rownum=1), 'NA') AS CCodeName, Its working fine. Is there any consequences of using rownum=1 here ?

Comment: That sounds like the LCODE column in your lookup table is not unique. That seems a bit strange - normally, you're looking up a single row. I would suggest you look at your table and either fix the data or find the unique key that you need to join on (maybe more than one column defines what you should be using to lookup a particular row).

Answer (score 3):

You can try joining the `Calendar` table to the `Lookup` table twice, using each of the two codes.

```
SELECT
    c.Calname,
    c.CCode,
    c.PCode,
    COALESCE(t1.Name, 'NA') AS CCodeName,
    COALESCE(t2.Name, 'NA') AS PCodeName
FROM Calendar c
LEFT JOIN Lookup t1
    ON c.CCode = t1.LCode
LEFT JOIN Lookup t2
    ON c.PCode = t2.LCode
```

Comment: This should not be happening with the sample data you showed.  You should post your actual data.

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much Tim. :)